Amen to baruch shem kvod malkuto l'olam va'ed
When someone messes up a bracha they say "Baruch shem kvod malkuto l'olam va'ed". Are we supposed to say Amen? They did not intend to say Baruch shem....  So is it counted as valid bracha?

https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.214.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Useful?
